# Why does git remember changes, but not let me stage them?

Tags: git, version-control

I have a list of modifications when I run `git status`, but I cannot stage them or commit them. How can I fix this?

This occurred after pulling the kernelmode directory from a bare repository somewhere in one huge commit.

```
% git status
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   kernelmode/linux-2.6.33/Documentation/IO-mapping.txt
#   ...

$ git add kernelmode/linux-2.6.33/Documentation/IO-mapping.txt

$ git status
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   kernelmode/linux-2.6.33/Documentation/IO-mapping.txt
#   ...
```

Comment: This is an odd situation, can you think of anything you did recently before this started to happen? What happens if you commit? what's the output of `git diff` and `git diff --cached`?

Answer (score 1):

`git add -u` should stage all your modifications.

Answer (score 0):

```
git add kernelmode/linux-2.6.33/Documentation/IO-mapping.txt
```

This should add the one file you show as needing to be staged.

However, some experimentation with two levels of sub-directory (instead of three as in the question) suggests that `git add .` should be adding everything that needs to be added - and for you, it is not.

Comment: Adding specific files makes no difference. :(

Comment: @Andres: That's odd...could it be that there's a sub-ordinate `.git` directory between your current directory and kernelmode/linux-2.6.33/Documentation/ that is not quite being handled properly?  That is, because the intermediate `.git` exists, the changes to IO-mapping.txt belong to the other Git repository, but for some reason the local 'git status' is not recognizing this properly?  Pretty far-fetched an unlikely, but...then so is what you are seeing.

Comment: Yeah. I have a feeling the other guy working on this repository did something funny...